# Can I setup SAML IDP without ADFS?

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs

I want to setup a SAML 2.0 Identity Provider, without the overhead of ADFS. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can do it using any other SAML IDP implementation.

Examples include:

[Shibboleth](https://shibboleth.net/)

[SimpleSAMLPHP](https://simplesamlphp.org/)

[OpenAM](https://forgerock.org/openam/)

[SSOCircle](http://www.ssocircle.com/en/)

[Auth0](https://auth0.com)